Rust Rayon ThreadPool: 'Cannot borrow as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a Fn closure'
I am trying to learn Rust's Rayon library by making a simple vector addition function. My current code is this, assuming a, b and c are vectors initialized to the same length, c is mutable and num_threads is a usize variable:
let pool = ThreadPoolBuilder::new().num_threads(num_threads).build()
           .expect("Could not create thread pool");
pool.install(|| {
    (0..c.len()).into_par_iter().for_each(|x| {
        c[x] = a[x] + b[x];
    });
});

But I get the error
error[E0596]: cannot borrow c as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a Fn closure
    c[x] = a[x].wrap_add(b[x]);
    ^ cannot borrow as mutable

I also want to note that ultimately I aim to make benchmark software, which is why I'm using thread pooling to specify the number of threads, but I think the extra closure pool.install() uses is part of where the issue is coming from. Modifying the global thread pool also isn't an option since that can only be done once, and I will want to re-run benchmarks with different thread numbers. I would also like to avoid using scope - if that's the only solution, so be it - since that would add a performance penalty.
I understand fundamentally what Rayon doesn't like here: chapter 4.2 of the Rust Book says that you can't have multiple mutable references to a variable, which is essentially what each thread would be getting. However, aside from the particular question of how I could get this code to work, this raises some other questions.
I can't seem to even move a reference to c into the thread pool closure. Why is this a restriction? Surely the power of multithreading is to get multiple threads to concurrently do some work on related data, so why can't I pass data to the threads this way?
Assuming I could get a reference to c into the thread pool, would there be some way to make it so that, for instance, thread 0 gets &mut c[0], thread 1 gets &mut c[1], and so on? If Rayon's purpose is to abstract some of the boilerplate of Rust's basic multithreading library, shouldn't this be something Rayon tries to make simpler?
Some other answers I have seen imply that iterating over the contents of the vectors themselves would help, but since I need all three vectors I would need to use izip. Doing this (replacing (0..c.len().into_par_iter()... with izip!(&a.mat, &b.mat, &mut c.mat).into_par_iter()...) gives me the error
error[E0599]: the method into_par_iter exists for struct Map<Zip<Zip<Iter<'_, T>, Iter<'_, T>>, IterMut<'_, T>>, {closure@lib.rs:303:9}>, but its trait bounds were not satisfied

izip!(&a.mat, &b.mat, &mut c.mat).into_par_iter().for_each(|x| {
   |                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `std::iter::Map<std::iter::Zip<std::iter::Zip<std::slice::Iter<'_, T>, std::slice::Iter<'_, T>>, std::slice::IterMut<'_, T>>, {closure@/home/richard/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/itertools-0.12.1/src/lib.rs:303:9: 303:10}>: rayon::iter::ParallelIterator`
           which is required by `std::iter::Map<std::iter::Zip<std::iter::Zip<std::slice::Iter<'_, T>, std::slice::Iter<'_, T>>, std::slice::IterMut<'_, T>>, {closure@/home/richard/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/itertools-0.12.1/src/lib.rs:303:9: 303:10}>: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
           `&std::iter::Map<std::iter::Zip<std::iter::Zip<std::slice::Iter<'_, T>, std::slice::Iter<'_, T>>, std::slice::IterMut<'_, T>>, {closure@/home/richard/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/itertools-0.12.1/src/lib.rs:303:9: 303:10}>: rayon::iter::ParallelIterator`
           which is required by `&std::iter::Map<std::iter::Zip<std::iter::Zip<std::slice::Iter<'_, T>, std::slice::Iter<'_, T>>, std::slice::IterMut<'_, T>>, {closure@/home/richard/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/itertools-0.12.1/src/lib.rs:303:9: 303:10}>: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`
           `&mut std::iter::Map<std::iter::Zip<std::iter::Zip<std::slice::Iter<'_, T>, std::slice::Iter<'_, T>>, std::slice::IterMut<'_, T>>, {closure@/home/richard/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/itertools-0.12.1/src/lib.rs:303:9: 303:10}>: rayon::iter::ParallelIterator`
           which is required by `&mut std::iter::Map<std::iter::Zip<std::iter::Zip<std::slice::Iter<'_, T>, std::slice::Iter<'_, T>>, std::slice::IterMut<'_, T>>, {closure@/home/richard/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/itertools-0.12.1/src/lib.rs:303:9: 303:10}>: rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator`


which seems to imply that references are now being moved into the closure. What gives? Why were they not being moved before?

You should include a complete example showing the problem. At the very least include the full error message. In particular the error which says ... its trait bounds were not satisfied ...  will also typically include an explanation of WHICH trait bound was expected (and where it was introduced) and which type doesn't satisfy that trait.

I've added more detail to the trait bounds error message, but I'm not sure how much it will help with how much of a tangle it is.

Suppose that in the 1st program you wrote instead c[0] = a[x] + b[x]. Clearly this has a data race and is invalid. However the types of c[0] and c[x] are indistinguishable, so the first method cannot work. (Keep in mind that Rust uses the type system to enforce parallel correctness like "no data races").

For the 2nd program, it expands the full namespaces of all the types, which is a bit noisy. But it is telling you: std::iter::Map< ... > does not satisfy the trait rayon::iter::ParallelIterator. If you look at the doc page for ParallelIterator you will see that there is in fact no such trait implementation, but rayon provides its own Zip trait. You may have more success using that parallel Zip

Your suggestion about parallel Zip helped very much, thank you! I'm still not sure what you mean by "the types of c[0] and c[x] are indistinguishable" though. If I'm explicitly iterating over all 3 vectors, each of the same type, surely the types should be accounted for already? Is the compiler just not catching that I'm accessing each element of c only once?

"Is the compiler just not catching that I'm accessing each element of c only once?" - indeed, the type checker only knows that c is a Vec and x is a number, it doesn't know that c is safe to access in parallel if you only access each index once, nor does it know the iterator accesses each index only once. Since it can't tell the different between c[x] and c[0], and it must reject assigning c[0] = ..  in parallel since this is clearly wrong, so it must also reject assigning c[x] = .. in parallel (because it cannot distinguish them)

The first thing you should do is write your code as a normal iterator, strictly with a chain of iterator methods.
c.iter_mut()
    .zip(&a)
    .zip(&b)
    .for_each(|((c, &a), &b)| *c = a + b);

This can be converted directly to a multithreaded version by adding par_, no other changes necessary. This is the ideal scenario for Rayon.
pool.install(|| {
    c.par_iter_mut()
        .zip(&a)
        .zip(&b)
        .for_each(|((c, &a), &b)| *c = a + b);
});

And Rayon provides implementations of IntoParallelIterator for tuples, which allows you to make an equivalent version that's even simpler.
pool.install(|| {
    (&mut c, &a, &b)
        .into_par_iter()
        .for_each(|(c, &a, &b)| *c = a + b);
});

Note that not all situations will be so simple. In particular, if you need to have only one of something per thread, look at the _init or _with methods. Iterators that need to accumulate into a single value will often need to use fold and reduce. Be sure to read through the methods of ParallelIterator and IndexedParallelIterator to find what works best for your situation.

I've figured out a solution. I needed to be more explicit about borrowing c by using an iterator in the thread pool's closure - which also seems to account for the "Assuming I could..." part of my question - as well as @user2407038 's suggestion of parallel zip:
let pool = ThreadPoolBuilder::new().num_threads(num_threads).build()
           .expect("Could not create thread pool");
pool.install(|| {
    (&mut c).into_par_iter().zip(0..c.len()).for_each(|x| {
        *x.0 = a[x.1] + b[x.1];
    });
});


.zip(0..c.len()) is so common, it has it's own method IndexedParallelIterator::enumerate ableit with flipped index and value.
